# How to run a code once in vb.net for a class?

Tags: vb.net

Basically I have a class with a static shared member. I want a code that run once to initiate that static shared member.

```
Class algorithm
    Public name As String
    Public lowPriceatNiceHash As Double
    Public highPriceatNiceHash As Double
    Public fixedPriceatNicehash As Double

    Shared dictOfAlgorithm As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, algorithm)
End Class
```

Now that dictOfAlgorithm dictionary should be set to a new empty one at a start of the use of the class. One and only one time.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize it where its declared:

```
Class ...

    Public Shared dictOfAlgorithm As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, algorithm) = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, algorithm)

End Class
```

or use the .cctor:

```
Class ...

    '' Shared .ctor, called once the first time the class is accessed.
    Shared Sub New()
        dictOfAlgorithm = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, algorithm)
    End Sub

    Public Shared dictOfAlgorithm As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, algorithm)

End Class
```

Comment: what is cctor? Yea I've heard they have that.

Comment: Can a Shared Sub New be declared Public?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b Yes it can, the Sub New is just the construction of the object, and is ran when the new keyword is used to create the object. It can have any access modifier, but the shared usually indicates that it's initializing a shared variable :)

Comment: @ProNinjaCat When trying to declare a Public Shared Sub New the Public keyword is highlighted.

Comment: @JimThio .cctor is commonly used as an abbreviation for a static constructor or Class ConstrucTOR. Its origin comes from the string that it returned when you're using reflection to get get caller info and have specified the CallerMemberName attribute. - See here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653987.aspx

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b: you are correct, access modifiers can not be applied to the .cctor.